# Accessing custom HTTP Response Header via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created an HTTP Response Header in IIS 7. I can see it in Fiddler but I can't get its value in C#.
Response.Headers.ToString() doesn't show the custom HTTP Response Headers.

How can I access its value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is IIS that is adding this response header you might not be able to read it in your application as this header might be added much later in the execution pipeline when the ASP.NET application has finished serving the request.

Comment: I see. The response header is added by IIS after the server side code ran, when it's packing the response to be sent to the browser. Makes sense. Thanks!